# Rolled up Amount till last Period in OBIEE11G

Tags: obiee

I have a requirement where we need to get "Amount" measure, rolled up  till last period , ToDate time series function will rolled up till current period but i want it till last period.

This needs to be in RPD only

Please give me your suggestion on this

Thanks,

Naveen

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: yes i tried,but couldn't achieve

Comment: Please still edit your post to include what code you do have, not working code is still useful for people to answer.

Comment: We need to know what you tried. I am going to suggest an initialization block in the RPD that sets a dynamic RPD variable, but I need to know what you have tried previously; maybe that won't work for you.